# Deja Dup restore fails with unknown error, creates a folder instead of a file

Tags: partitioning, backup, restore, deja-dup

reviewing a bit about it, I found this unsolved question in another forum that perfectly describes my downside:

> I'm a relative noob. I am running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Backed up a folder
> on my Data drive which is formatted as NTFS and that I use both from
> Windows10 (***Windows 11 for me***) and Ubuntu using Deja Dup and without encrypting the backup
> file.
>
> I wanted to test that it works and then deleted a test file from the
> backed up folder and tried restoring it from backup by right-clicking
> and selecting the Restore Missing Files... option. Everything seems to
> work fine. It correctly picks up the file I deleted as missing from
> the backup and then I go through the steps of selecting the file to
> restore and click Forward and then on the Summary window I click
> Restore. It then says Restoring Files and after a few seconds I get
> asked to authenticate Authentication is needed to run
> '/usr/libexec/-deja-dup/duplicity' as the super user. I then enter my
> password.

[image]
[image]

> One or two seconds later it fails with Restore failed Failed with an
> unknown error. An interesting thing I noted was that it creates a folder with the
> name of the file I wanted to restore before bombing out, but not the
> file itself.

[image]
[image]

> After doing some reading up I could decipher that Deja Dup is just
> calling Duplicity which is actually doing the work. I then tried
> restoring the file using a terminal in the hope that it would give me
> more meaningful error messages to help trace the root cause.
>
> Restoring with duplicity from a terminal yielded the same result. I
> get prompted for a GnuPG passphrase which I then supply (I used the
> same password as my user and it seemed to accept it).
>
> It also creates just an empty directory with the name of the file I am
> actually trying to restore.
>
> The funny thing is, if I go into Deja Dup and restore the entire
> backup into my home folder it works and I can then pick the file up
> from there. This is inconvenient though because it restores all the
> backed up files. I cannot just restore the file I want this way. But
> it is a workaround.
>
> I thought maybe it is because of the file systems being different
> (EXT4 - works, NTFS - doesn't work). Tried replicating the above step
> (restoring the full backup) from Deja Dup to a new folder on my Data
> drive and it fails the same way as when I tried the single file. This
> sort of supports my theory, but I'm not sure.
>
> Any advice anyone?

I have added a couple of images to complement it, but there is not much more I can say. Thanks.

Comment: From your screenshots it shows your backup is on a Google Drive. If that is via Ubuntu "online accounts" settings then it will not support all file system commands. It supports basic file operations but not all and that could well be the reason for your problems. Try backing up to/from proper file system/disk mounts and you will probably find all works correctly. If so, then the problem is the Google mount and not deja-dup/duplicity. I use this to mount google drive and it seems to support everything just like a normal file system: https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse

Comment: Oh sure! I hadn't thought that that might be the problem. So I wonder why they add the Google Drive option, if it doesn't work. I will test what you comment. Thanks